# Missing required parameters for route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to ask how to fix this error. I have this error Missing required parameters for `[Route: userprofile.edit] [URI: userprofile/{userprofile}/edit]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\code\task1\resources\views\userprofile\create.blade.php)`

I have user informations in view `userprofile\create.blade.php` and after submitting the button I want to relocate the page on the `userprofile\edit.blade.php`

This is my `userProfileController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;

class userProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view("userprofile.create");
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        return view('userprofile.edit')->withUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Also the route for this views

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'User'], function(){
 Route::get('/userprofile/{id}/edit', ['as' => 'userprofile.edit', 'uses' => 'userProfileController@edit']);
});


Route::resource('userprofile','userProfileController');
```

And my route action in the button in `create.blade.php`

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" action="{{ route('userprofile.edit') }}" value="Edit profile">
```

If you have any idea why is this error, please write me!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add action to a input field. Add action to `form` tag. You are not passing any **id** in the form action. Add id to your action like I have passed **id = 1**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('userprofile.edit', ['id' => 1]) }}">
```

Update

First of all you have to create a user with given data and after that you redirect to the edit page with the generated id.

Comment: After submitting the button I have the same view with changed route localhost:8080/code/task1/public/userprofile/create?user_name=admin%40example.com

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" action="{{ route('userprofile.edit') }}" value="Edit profile">
```

use

```
<a href="{{url('/userprofile/'.PROFILE ID.'/edit')" class="btn btn-primary" >Edit profile</a>
```

PROFILE ID must be id

Comment: why you use url instead of route?

Comment: after I change that and submitting the button i have the same view and the route change to this http://localhost:8080/code/task1/public/userprofile/create?user_name=admin%40example.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a default value for the id passed in to the `edit` and other methods, like so:

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    return view('userprofile.edit')->withUser($user);
}
```

Here, we are setting the default value of `id` to `null`. Next, check in your method if it is null and if so, return with an error or whatever you wanna do in that situation:

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    if(!$id)
      return back()->with(['error'=>'No document selected for editing.']);

    $user = User::find($id);
    return view('userprofile.edit')->withUser($user);
}
```

**`if(!$id)
   return back()->with(['error'=>'No document selected for editing.']);`**

This is your check and if the id is null, we simply return back and notify the user (You must check for the error in your blade view and display it if it exists).

Comment: I don't have problems with setting the value of id, the method give me the right id, but i have problem with relocating the page to edit.blade.php